# chat in android with service

Tags: android, service, chat

I want to create a chat application using service, Here service should listen to new messages, notifies user if new message arrives from server and then when user clicks on notification, it shows complete message details. Again if user wants to send a message, it has to send the message back to user.

Here I want to start service only once and run indefinitely, But when activity starts it's starting service each time.

consider server as chat.socket.io

Please tell me how to achieve the solution. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is only loaded already, it won't load it again. The intent will be delivered to the same service. So you don't have to worry about that.

Also, you might want to use Google Cloud Messaging instead of making services for chat like notifications.